# Purchasing sd card will solve "insufficient memory storage" issue?

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

After unsuccesfully rooting my android 4.1.1 tab,I can't download anny apps even though I still have 4 gb of 
free memory on my internal storage.

I've done factory resetting but it didn work,will inserting an sd card possibly resolve my concern?

Can I restore apps I lost by doing this?

Comment: "I can't download anny apps even though I still have 4 gb of free memory" <- you're supplying way too little information. Why can't you download any apps? What is your error message?

Answer (score 1):

Buying a new SD card will not solve the problem. In Android phones, all applications are installed in internal memory. Some apps/games which ask for big data to be downloaded from the net also save the data in internal memory. So, if you insert external memory card in your device, then still you face same problem.

To solve this, first you need a external SD card; at least 8GB more would be better. Then, you need to configure your device so that it forcibly installs all data on external SD card. For more information, [read this](http://droid-den.com/android-guides/android-guide-force-apps-to-the-sd-card-without-rooting-a2sd/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure by factory resetting all your apps are lost. What you can do is login your account in Play Store and click My Apps, and redownload all your lost stuff again.

I'm not sure though if plugging in an SD card will solve your issue with downloading apps, but when my phone with ICS didn't have an SD card even though it has an internal storage, it wouldn't let me capture photos. My bet is, yes you need to plugin an SD card. Try borrowing one first and see if that solves your problem, then buy one. I think you should definitely buy one though, for your media like music, photos and videos.

One more thing, if you don't want to lose apps, I suggest you download [Appmonster](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=appmonster&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.android_telefonie.appmanager&hl=en&ei=5irlUI2oHcKsjALfhYEQ&usg=AFQjCNFNWK9j-vAYuab69vYQ4SN7yFAW0Q&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.cGE). It saves your applications as apk files in your external storage. What does this mean? You can backup all your apps, revert to older versions of applications, and even save app memory. Just uninstall the apps you don't need and install them whenever you need them. All this, without having to go to the Play Store.